# column control component doesn't work properly aem6.0

Tags: aem

I need to use 2-column component. But when I add this component to the page and try to edit it, it doesn't give any option in the "column layout" dropdown.

also, by default it adds 2 rows, not the columns.

Any idea about this?

Same is the case with 3 columns and column control components, "column layout" dropdown doesn't show anything.

Comment: If no option is coming in layout then post the value you configured in col-ctrl in design mode. There can be the issue in js/css files. Mention the error as well, If any.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually didn't put any values in design mode(allowed formats). I thought it gives 2 columns(both 50%) by default. Could u please let me know what is the format of the values that we give in the design mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the col-ctrl in design mode and add sample values as given in OOTB component.

```
2;cq-colctrl-lt0    2 Columns (50%, 50%)
3;cq-colctrl-lt1    3 Columns (33%, 33%, 33%)
4;cq-colctrl-lt2    4 Columns (16%, 16%, 16%, 33%)
4;cq-colctrl-lt3    4 Columns (25%, 25%, 25%, 25%)
5;cq-colctrl-lt4    5 Columns (20%, 20%, 20%, 20%, 20%)
```

Refer [Link](http://www.6dglobal.com/blogs/creating-column-control-adobe-cq-2012-02-07) for more info.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks! It works! Only thing is it adds rows instead of columns. For eg. if I select 2 columns(50%, 50%), it is adding 2 rows. Any idea to resolve this issue?